# Java: I can't get it to loop, somethings wrong with the boolean but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Boolean yn;
    String answer;
    String name;

    do{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hi "+name);
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another name?");
        System.out.println("y/n?");
        answer = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if(answer.equals("y")){
                yn = true;
                break;
            }else if(answer.equals("n")){
                yn = false;
                break;
            }


    }while(yn = true );


}
}
```

i have to make it go back to asking the name when i get a yes for the last question.
super noob here sorry please help.

Comment: `while(yn = true );` here you are assigning value to `yn`. you have to use `while(yn == true)` or you can use `while(yn)` because `yn` itself is `boolean` then no need the again and evaluate to boolean value :)

Comment: Remove the break statement because it will exit the loop. You can move the `do` statement to below `System.out.println("Enter your name");` so that when you say yes, the program will wait for your input again without asking for the name again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` is the culprit...

When you use `break` it breaks out of the loop.

So use, (Note: You don't need an else if, just else should be sufficient).

```
        if(answer.equals("y")){
            yn = true;
        } else {
            yn = false;
        }
```

without `break` statement.

Also use a condition (not assignment) inside while,

```
while(yn == true)
```

or simply,

```
while(yn)
```

Comment: i removed the breaks
and changed  the while(yn = true) to while(yn)
error: yn might not have been initialized

Comment: Oh, ya... your condition is not satisfying all the flows... Change your `else if` to just `else`...

Comment: if i remove the if it says ";" expected

Answer (score 0):

The `break` should not be used in an `if` statement only if you want to close the `loop`, remove `break` from `if`.

Answer (score -1):

use continue instead of break as below

```
if(answer.equals("y")){
    yn = true;
    break;  //use continue here
} else if(answer.equals("n")){
    yn = false;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
Boolean yn;
String answer;
String name;
do {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hi "+name);
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another name?");
        System.out.println("y/n?");
        answer = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            if(answer.equals("y")){
                yn = true;
                continue;   //Continue does not terminate the loop instead of break
            }else {
                yn = false;
                break;
            }
    }while(yn = true );

}
```